# C functions wrapped with f2py return only zeros

Tags: python, c, f2py

I am trying to wrap a simple C function using f2py. It compiles all right, but the function returns only zero. I am a novice in C, so I am pretty sure making a silly mistake there.

For example, the c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void Test(double x, double y)
{
  x = y*2;
}
```

The pyf file:

```
python module test
interface
   subroutine Test(x, y)        
     intent (c) Test  ! is a C function
     intent (c)         ! all arguments are considered as C based
     double precision intent(in)     :: x
     double precision intent(out)    :: y
   end subroutine Test
end interface
end python module test
```

Comment: Can you also post the f2py compile line and python code where you test it.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem, you need

1. To use pointers for the return variable in the `.c` function as mentioned by @mgilson,

   ```
   void Test(double *x, double y)
   {
      *x = y * 2;
   }
   ```
2. Specify in the `.pyf` interface that pointers are used, which is incidentally identical arrays of size 1,

   ```
   double precision intent(out)   :: x(1)
   double precision intent(in)    :: y
   ```

The `test.Test` function will then return not a scalar, but a numpy ndarray of length 1, containing that scalar. Still, I'm not sure if there is another way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in `C`, but I think your variables need to be pointers for anything to change:

```
void Test(double *x, double *y)
{
  *x = *y * 2;
}
```

Comment: @melpomene -- Thanks -- As I said, I'm not expert in C :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer tip and, yes, the  intent(in)/(out) need to be switched, my bad. However, I am still having the same problem. Even if I make an assignment within the function, say, *y =z it still returns zero. Inserting printf("%d\n",*y) into the function also prints zero.

Comment: @Meddle When `y` is `double*` then `*y` is `double`, so you should `printf` it with `"%f"` format, not `"%d"`...

Comment: @mgilson: Have you tested your code? I get the same result as Meddle, the return value is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: my first answer was wrong, the values should indeed be passed to C as pointers, as pointed out by others.

```
void Test(double* x, double* y)
{
    *y = *x * 2;
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't work: the return value is empty in this case. I don't think `f2py` handles C's `return` statement, instead you have to assign the output value to a variable that's described in the `pyf` file. Or am I misunderstanding something about your answer?

Comment: Yeah sorry, my bad, I mostly used `f2py` with fortran and when it wraps fortran code, it will actually build it to `C` first and that `C`-code actually has return values. I simply assumed that you would have to write the same `C`-code when using `f2py` with `C`. Looking into the documentation, that's not the case, though. It should indeed be all pointer arguments.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update. I still can't get it to work: your edited code gives me a segfault when I call it from Python.

Comment: Just to make sure: can you try this with python arrays as input ? The documentation on ScyPy says that it should work by declaring the types as is in `C`. I'm not really sure about it. Here's the link: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/f2py_and_NumPy